# How many percent in classification accuracy could be considered as significant

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, accuracy

I have 2 classification methods to classify 6 classes. The method 1 achieved the accuracy = A1%, and the method 2 achieved A2%, with A2 > A1.

How many percentage point between A2 and A1 could be considered as "A2 is significant better than A1" (they both run on the same data set)

Comment: It does not work like that. But you could use bootstrap to get an average accuracy of your algorithm for your dataset. Then do it again for the second algorithm. It will give you two distributions. And that way you can make a test to determine if both mean are equal or not.

Comment: Could I use cross - validation (let's say 5-folds) and then compare the average accuracy?